# Having trouble with sage

Tags: sagetex

I don't seem to be able to produce a .sty file following the instructions from links given to me in a previous post,

my log file gives me this:

```latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.1) (preloaded format=pdftex 2022.9.12)  18 SEP 2022 11:16
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**/Users/paulallen/Desktop/AllLatex/sage/sage2
(/Users/paulallen/Desktop/AllLatex/sage/sage2
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
? H
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \usepackage
               {sagetex}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \begin
          {document}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 your \LaTeX
               {} document. For example, there are
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \sage 
                      
l.8 $\sage
          {number_of_partitions(1269)}$ integer partitions of $1269$.
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 \begin
           {sageblock}
? 
[1{/Users/paulallen/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/fonts/map/pd
ftex/pdftex.map}] )</Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/fonts/ty
pe1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/i
nstall/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb></Library/Application Support/M
iKTeX/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on sage2.pdf (1 page, 37777 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I have tried to run the example Tex twice as recommended but it still it doesn't give me a .sty file, I just get the ?? marks in the final PDF, any help would be appreciated this is doing my head in as all the literature makes it seem so easy.

Comment: you need to use pdflatex not pdftex for latex files (whether or not you use sage)

Comment: 1. David Carlisle is right: use pdflatex, 2. Running latex doesn't create a `.sty` file, it gives you a `sagetex.sage` file that you must process with Sage. 3. Running Sage on the file creates a `.sout` file. This will tell you why you get ?? 4. The [documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html) under "Make SageTeX known to TeX" gives you several methods deal with style file problems. The simplest is to copy the file that comes with Sage into the same directory as your LaTeX document.